# patch.multiple() returns an empty dictionary

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a pytest fixture mocking multiple methods of an API client, using [`patch.multiple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def client_mock(request):    
    with patch.multiple(api_client,
                        method1=MagicMock(return_value=fixture1),
                        method2=MagicMock(return_value=fixture2),
                        method3=MagicMock(return_value=fixture3)) as mocks:
        yield mocks
```

This seems to work fine, however, when I try to access the mocks (by adding a `client_mock` parameter to a test function), I get an empty dictionary (`{}`). Why does it not contain any mocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`patch.multiple` does not return the values in the context manager if the mocks are already provided - only if you use the automatic creation of mocks using `DEFAULT`.

If you need to access the mocks in your tests, you can use `DEFAULT` and adapt the mocks after they are created:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, DEFAULT

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def client_mock():    
    with patch.multiple(api_client,
                        method1=DEFAULT,
                        method2=DEFAULT,
                        method3=DEFAULT) as mocks:
        mocks['method1'].return_value = fixture1
        mocks['method2'].return_value = fixture2
        mocks['method3'].return_value = fixture3

        yield mocks
```

or you can construct the mocks beforehand and create the returned dictionary yourself:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def client_mock():
    mock1 = MagicMock(return_value=fixture1)
    mock2 = MagicMock(return_value=fixture2)
    mock3 = MagicMock(return_value=fixture3)
    with patch.multiple(api_client,
                        method1=mock1,
                        method2=mock2,
                        method3=mock3):
        yield {'method1': mock1, 'method2': mock2, 'method3': mock3}
```

The usual case is probably that you just want to patch the objects and don't need to access them in the tests. In this case you can just use:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def client_mock(request):    
    with patch.multiple(api_client,
                        method1=MagicMock(return_value=fixture1),
                        method2=MagicMock(return_value=fixture2),
                        method3=MagicMock(return_value=fixture3)):
        yield
```

I agree that the documentation for this is not very clear, so that it may cause such misunderstandings.